# unable to use DateTime in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using DateTime in controller as:

```
public function index()
  {
    $seats=seats::all();
    $date = date('Y-M-D');
    $tomorrow= new \DateTime('tomorrow');
        $nextday= new \DateTime('tomorrow + 1day');
        return view('bus.busview',['mytime'=>$date,'seats'=>$seats,'nextday'=>

$nextday,'tomorrow'=>$tomorrow]);

}
```

but while using these variables in view:

```
Your Name: <input type="name" name="name" id="name" ><br><BR>
Your Contact No. <input type="contact" name="contact" id="contact" ><br><BR>
Todays date:<mark>{{$mytime}}</mark><br><br>
tomorrows date:{{$tomorrow}}
Book for: <select>
  <option name="select" value="{{$mytime}}">Today</option>
  <option name="select" value="{{$tomorrow}}">Tomorrow</option>
  <option name="select" value="{{$nextday}}">{{$nextday}}</option>
  <option name="select" value="{{$nextday}}">{{$nextday}}</option>
</select>
```

i am getting this error:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to display object instead of it's property or result of it's method:

```
{{ $nextday }}
```

You should display something like this:

```
{{ $nextday->format('d') }}
```